# How to store data (Ex. 100 rows) from database column to a variable in JMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter

1. Connected to database using JDBC Connection configuration
2. Added JDBC Request to the thread (Given "Result variable name as 'AccountNumber'")
3. Using the query fetched 100 rows in Column1

Now, I want to store this 100 rows in a variable and pass this variable to another thread so that I can use the values from this variable to pass as a parameter for different thread counts.

Please help me in sorting out the issue.

Tried using the below code, but it is only storing the last value into the variable instead of all the rows from db

```
int i = 0;
    while (i<vars.getObject("AssetNumber").size())
{   
    String ContractNumber = vars.getObject("AssetNumber").get(i).get("ASSET_NUM") + "";
vars.put("ContractNumber",ContractNumber);

log.info(" Unique value of AccountNumber:  " + ContractNumber);
log.info(" ASSET_NUM:  " + ContractNumber);
i++;
}
```

Need a script to store all the values from db related to specific column to be stored in the variable so that I can use the variable in another threads and pass the values as parameters

Comment: Can anyone please help me with the above question posted. Looking for your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you're overwriting the `ContractNumber` variable value on each iteration of your [while loop](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_while_loop).

My expectation is that you need to change this line:

```
vars.put("ContractNumber",ContractNumber)
```

to something like:

```
vars.put("ContractNumber",vars.get("ContractNumber") + ContractNumber)
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Using the above mentioned script is displaying the variable as below
SCript Used:
 int i = 0;
 while (i<vars.getObject("AssetNumber").size())
  
{ String ContractNumber = vars.getObject("AssetNumber").get(i).get("ASSET_NUM");
 //vars.put("ContractNumber",ContractNumber);
 vars.put("ContractNumber",vars.get("ContractNumber") + ContractNumber);

  log.info(" Unique value of AccountNumber:  " + ContractNumber);
  log.info(" ASSET_NUM:  " + ContractNumber);
  i++;

} 
Variable value is displaying as below
ContractNumber=null2020060831996620200608319974